# initial value problem $y'=-y^2, y(1)= \sqrt{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

hey I cant seem to solve this at all, not sure how you do it with no x values

$$y'=-y^2, y(1)= \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: This is a seperable ODE. The initial conditions give you the point $(x,y)=(1,\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: since $y' = {dy\over dx}$ we get: $$\int {dy\over y^2} = -\int dx$$

Comment: But we don't know if $y& is never equal to $0$. If there were some points where $y=0$ then we couldn't devide the equation by $y^2$

Comment: If $y=0$ then $y'=0=-y^2$. I believe this is called the trivial solution.

Comment: yes thanks, I kinda understand

Comment: @Axion004 That takes care of the case where $y$ is identically $0$. But there's still a problem: If $y=0$ at just one point we can't use the solution as a separable equation...

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis See the answer II just posted. (When I wrote it I thought I was answering the OO's  question, but I see I was actuually addressing _your_ comment...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Now I think problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

The standard technique for separable equations gives $$y=\frac1{x+c}.$$Now you ask what if $y=0$ at some point? Then that technique doesn't work.

**Non-mathematical comment:** If this is homework for a standard DE class I guarantee you that the grader will not expect you to worry about that, you can just ignore the issue.

Of course that doesn't solve the problem. (Pointing out that $y=0$ is the trivial solution also doesn't resolve the issue -  that applies if $y$ is *identically* $0$, not if it's just $0$  at some point.)

In fact $y\ne0$, which you can prove as follows:

We're given that $y(1)\ne0$. Since $y$ is continuous (being differentiable) it follows that there exist $a,b$ with $a<1<b$ such that $y$ has no zero in the open interval $(a,b)$.

Suppose (to get a contradiction) that there exists $x>1$ with $y(x)=0$. Since $y$ is continuous, there is a *smallest* $ B>1$ such that $y(B)=0$. So $y\ne0$ on the interval $[1,B)$, and so the separable-equation technique shows that there exists $c$ such that $$y(x)=\frac1{x+c}\quad\text{if } 1\le x<B.$$

But again $y$ is continuous, hence $y(B)=1/(B+c)$, which implies $y(B)\ne0$, contradiction.

Similarly $y(x)\ne0$ for $x<1$.

(If you didn't follow that sorry; none of the students in my DE classes would follow it, which is why we ignore this sort of issue in that class.)

**Note** *If* you know the standard existence and uniqueness theorem then it follows that there's no problem: $y=1/(x+c)$ is a solution to the given IVP (for an appropriate $c$), hence it's the only solution, hence the solution never vanishes.

The second proof looks simpler, but in fact if you add in the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem it's much harder; the point to the first proof I gave is we don't need that big theorem.

Someone asks about the general case. Turns out it's never a problem.

**Edit:** In a previous version I said something assuming that if $\phi$ abd $\psi$ are Lipschitz on all of $\Bbb R$ then $y'=\phi(y)$, $u(x_0)=y_0$ has a solution valid on all of $\Bbb R$. That's nonsense; in fact the IVP in the OP *shows* it's nonsense. But it *is* true that where there *is* a solution we must have $\phi(y(x))\ne0$, so if a solution exists on an interval it *is* given by $\int dy/\phi(y)=\int \psi(x)\,dx$:

> > **Thm.** Suppose $\alpha<\beta$, $x_0\in(\alpha,\beta)$, $\phi(y_0)\ne0$, and the IVP $y'=\psi(x)\phi(y),\quad y(x_0)=y_0$ has a solution on $(\alpha,\beta)$. Then $\phi(y(x))$ has no zero in $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Suppose otoh that $x_a\in(\alpha,\beta)$ and $\phi(y(x_1))=0$. Let $y_1=y(x_1)$. Now $z=y$ is a solution to the second  IVP $$z'=\psi(x)\phi(z),\,\,z(x_1)=y_1.$$But $z=y_1$ is also a solution to that second IVP, so uniqueness implies $y=y_1$. Hence $\phi(y_0)=\phi(y(x_0))=\phi(y_1)=0$, contradiction.

(So you can use the separable-equation technique as long as $\phi(y_0)\ne0$. Of course it can't work if $\phi(y_0)=0$, but in that case you don't need it; $y=y_0$ is the solution.)

Comment: When we have to solve seperable DE like this one should I always do that kind of proof in order to divide?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis I don't know about the general case, sorry.

Comment: Suppose that I find it as an exercise in an exam? What I should write in order to be mathematically correct?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis If you mean what if you have an IVP on an exam where this issue arises, to be mathematically correct you'd probably need to try to do something like what's above. **But** if it's an exam in the standard just-after-calculus DE class then as I said above, I'm certain you don't need to worry about the issue - the instructor will be happy if you just give the formal solution as a separable equation without worrying about what if $y$ vanishes at some point. (Or you could argue as in the second proof  I gave...)

Comment: Ok I understand! Thank you for spending time to answer my question!

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis Turns out there's no problem in the general case - see edit..

Comment: Again thank you for clarifying everything!

Answer (score 0):

We have $y'=-y^2 \iff \frac{y'}{-y^2}=1 \iff \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{y})=\frac{dx}{dx} \iff \frac{1}{y}=x+c$
$y(1)=\sqrt{2} \iff c=\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2}$

So $1/y=\frac{2x+\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\iff y=\frac{2}{2x+\sqrt{2}-2}$